# Test several calls to websocket

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, stomp

I'm trying stomp in spring for the first time. I created an endpoint similar to [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

```
@MessageMapping("/game")
@SendTo("/topic/status")
public GameStatus greeting(GameMessage message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor 
 headerAccessor) throws Exception {
}
```

Which (long story short) returns persisted data.

And similar to the tutorial, I'm testing it like this

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class GameIntegrationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private SockJsClient sockJsClient;

    private WebSocketStompClient stompClient;

    private final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
        this.sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

        this.stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
        this.stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    }

    @Test
    public void getGame() throws Exception {

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final AtomicReference<Throwable> failure = new AtomicReference<>();

        String[] board = { "1", "2", "X", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
        StompSessionHandler handlerPlayer = playerHandler(latch, failure, 3, board);

        this.stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:{port}/tictactoe-websocket", this.headers, handlerPlayer, this.port);

        if (latch.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            if (failure.get() != null) {
                throw new AssertionError("", failure.get());
            }
        } else {
            fail("Status not received");
        }

    }

    private StompSessionHandler playerHandler(CountDownLatch latch, AtomicReference<Throwable> failure, Integer postion,
            String[] board) {
        return new TestSessionHandler(failure) {

            @Override
            public void afterConnected(final StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
                session.subscribe("/topic/status", new StompFrameHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                        return GameStatus.class;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                        GameStatus gameStatus = (GameStatus) payload;
                        try {

                            assertArrayEquals(board, gameStatus.getBoard());
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            failure.set(t);
                        } finally {
                            session.disconnect();
                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                    }
                });
                try {
                    session.send("/app/game", new GameMessage("Spring", postion));
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    failure.set(t);
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private class TestSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

        private final AtomicReference<Throwable> failure;

        public TestSessionHandler(AtomicReference<Throwable> failure) {
            this.failure = failure;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            this.failure.set(new Exception(headers.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void handleException(StompSession s, StompCommand c, StompHeaders h, byte[] p, Throwable ex) {
            this.failure.set(ex);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable ex) {
            this.failure.set(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test a second call to the same endpoint in the same test to achieve

```
 boolean status= false;
 StompSessionHandler handlerPlayer1 = playerHandler(latch, failure, 5, status);
```

Any hint on how can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code, it works but looks like an overkill. Let me know if this looks ok

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class GameIntegrationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private WebSocketStompClient stompClientPlayerOne;
    private WebSocketStompClient stompClientPlayerTwo;

    private final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.stompClientPlayerOne = createClient();
        this.stompClientPlayerTwo = createClient();
    }

    @Test
    public void getGame() throws Exception {

        String[] board = { "1", "2", "X", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
        testNewConnection(board, 3, stompClientPlayerOne);

        String[] board1 = { "1", "2", "X", "4", "5", "6", "O", "8", "9" };
        testNewConnection(board1, 7, stompClientPlayerTwo);

    }

    private void testNewConnection(String[] board, Integer position, WebSocketStompClient stompClient)
            throws InterruptedException, AssertionError {
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final AtomicReference<Throwable> failure = new AtomicReference<>();
        StompSessionHandler handlerPlayer = playerHandler(latch, failure, position, board);
        stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:{port}/tictactoe-websocket", this.headers, handlerPlayer, this.port);
        waitIfFailure(latch, failure);
    }

    private void waitIfFailure(CountDownLatch latch, AtomicReference<Throwable> failure)
            throws InterruptedException, AssertionError {
        if (latch.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            if (failure.get() != null) {
                throw new AssertionError("", failure.get());
            }
        } else {
            fail("Status not received");
        }
    }

    private StompSessionHandler playerHandler(CountDownLatch latch, AtomicReference<Throwable> failure, Integer postion,
            String[] board) {
        return new TestSessionHandler(failure) {

            @Override
            public void afterConnected(final StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
                session.subscribe("/topic/status", new StompFrameHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                        return GameStatus.class;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                        GameStatus gameStatus = (GameStatus) payload;
                        try {

                            assertArrayEquals(board, gameStatus.getBoard());
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            failure.set(t);
                        } finally {
                            session.disconnect();
                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                    }
                });
                try {
                    session.send("/app/game", new GameMessage("Spring", postion));
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    failure.set(t);
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private WebSocketStompClient createClient() {
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
        var sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

        var stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        return stompClient;
    }

    private class TestSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

        private final AtomicReference<Throwable> failure;

        public TestSessionHandler(AtomicReference<Throwable> failure) {
            this.failure = failure;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            this.failure.set(new Exception(headers.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void handleException(StompSession s, StompCommand c, StompHeaders h, byte[] p, Throwable ex) {
            this.failure.set(ex);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable ex) {
            this.failure.set(ex);
        }
    }
}
```